# Is there a max lock timeout setting for MySql

Tags: mysql, timeout

If a transaction holds a lock on a table for over xx minutes, abort/rollback the transaction & release the lock.

Problem i am trying to solve:
One of the tables was locked for over an hour, to execute a slow update query. All other transactions which required locking the same table started failing since it could not acquire a lock.

The slow query was fixed, but wondering if there is a failsafe switch "max_lock_timeout" or so which can release a lock if it exceeds certain threshold.

Comment: Pls check all answers to the duplicate question, not just the accepted one.

Comment: There are no "table locks" in InnoDB.  The default for `lock_wait_timeout` is 50 seconds.  (Much too high in my opinion.)  There are techniques to help avoid such, but show us the conflicting queries.